# Command[zk] failed while trying to run Apache Druid

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I am very very new to Druid. I want to install it on my MacOS machine. I followed the instruction [on this page](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/).

When I run `./bin/start-druid`, I get the output below:

```
Arat-MBP-2:apache-druid-27.0.0 mustafamuratarat$ ./bin/start-druid
Please specify memory argument
```

Then I checked the folder downloaded, there are multiple configurations and I wanted to go for, `./bin/start-micro-quickstart` but this time, even though the server is starting on port 8888, I still get the error below:

```
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Starting Apache Druid.
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Open http://localhost:8888/ or http://Arat-MBP-2:8888/ in your browser to access the web console.
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Or, if you have enabled TLS, use https on port 9088.
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Starting services with log directory [/Users/mustafamuratarat/apache-druid-27.0.0/log].
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Running command[zk]: bin/run-zk conf
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Running command[coordinator-overlord]: bin/run-druid coordinator-overlord conf/druid/single-server/micro-quickstart
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Running command[broker]: bin/run-druid broker conf/druid/single-server/micro-quickstart
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Running command[router]: bin/run-druid router conf/druid/single-server/micro-quickstart
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Running command[historical]: bin/run-druid historical conf/druid/single-server/micro-quickstart
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:01 2023] Running command[middleManager]: bin/run-druid middleManager conf/druid/single-server/micro-quickstart
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:04 2023] Command[zk] exited (pid = 62143, exited = 1)
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:04 2023] Command[zk] failed, see its logfile for more details
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:07 2023] Running command[zk]: bin/run-zk conf
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:11 2023] Command[zk] exited (pid = 62264, exited = 1)
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:11 2023] Command[zk] failed, see its logfile for more details
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:14 2023] Running command[zk]: bin/run-zk conf
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:18 2023] Command[zk] exited (pid = 62292, exited = 1)
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:18 2023] Command[zk] failed, see its logfile for more details
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:21 2023] Running command[zk]: bin/run-zk conf
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:23 2023] Command[zk] exited (pid = 62321, exited = 1)
[Thu Nov  2 10:35:23 2023] Command[zk] failed, see its logfile for more details
.
.
.
```

I looked online but could not find anything.

By the way, I used Homebrew to install Kafka on my local machine, both kafka server and Zookeeper is installed.